# Using different client certificates for different routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ssl, iis

I'm working with an SSL application and I would like to read data from **two client certificates**.
When a user comes to my site he chooses a certificate and enters a pin, which get cached and used by subsequent requests until Chrome (et al) gets restarted.

Any ideas on how to prompt the user for a certificate for a second time on the same site?

Regards.

Comment: Did this link answer your question? [https://serverfault.com/questions/473670/how-to-force-a-browser-to-prompt-for-client-certificate-even-when-one-was-alrea](https://serverfault.com/questions/473670/how-to-force-a-browser-to-prompt-for-client-certificate-even-when-one-was-alrea).

Comment: @samwu Ah, no, it suggests revoking the certificate from the server's store, which is either not achievable from the application level, or just too complicated to be automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that has satisfied my need was to bind the app on **two https ports** in IIS config. Works on IIS Express also.

More info: I am making two ajax requests on routes that are matched by a single `<location>` tag web.config. This location requires a certificate, which means user gets prompted when accessing them. Since these two ajax calls go to different ports, user gets prompted on the second ajax call too.

Knowing how to clear the cache would have been nicer for other use cases, because restarting Chrome is not something I would ask my users to do.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark solution as answer.